# Dynamical system

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Please help!

How to show that $ \lim _{n→∞} \frac{x_{(n+1)}}{x_n} =\frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2}$ for a dynamical system 
$$x_{(n+1)}=x_n + y_n\\
y_{(n+1)}=x_n$$

Thank you!

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried? Is this from a class you're taking? If so, then what method have you discussed for solving such dynamical systems?

Comment: This is the recursive relationship for a [Fibonacci](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) sequence. The limit can be obtained from the explicit expression. The explicit expression can be obtained using, e.g.  generating functions.

Comment: Or by diagonalizing the system matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: hI, Omnomnomnom, I have tried Jacobian matrix and work out the two eigenvalues are (1+√5)/2 and (1-√5)/2, but don't know how to connect them to this question.

Comment: Hi, Aleksejs Fomins. I also have proven that this system is equivalent to a Fibonacci sequence. But don't know to apply it to this question.

Comment: Hi, Hans Lundmark, thank you for your reply.  I have don't this part.

Comment: I think I know how to answer this question now. Thank you for those who took the time to reply.

Answer (score 3):

From

$\left(\begin{array}{r} x_n \\ y_n \end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{rr} 1 ~~~1 \\ 1 ~~~0 \end{array}\right)^n\left(\begin{array}{r} x_0 \\ y_0 \end{array}\right)$

you get

$\left(\begin{array}{r} x_n \\ y_n \end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{rr} F_{n+1} ~~~F_n \\ F_n ~~~F_{n-1} \end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{r} x_0 \\ y_0 \end{array}\right)$

and the rest should be clear by using the explicit formula for the [Fibonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number),

e.g. have a look at the section *Matrix form*.

Comment: user90369, Great stuff, Thanks!

Comment: @Newbee : You're welcome! ;)

Answer (score 2):

We should firstly shift the second equation by $1$:
 $$y_{n+1}=x_n  \rightarrow y_n = x_{n-1}$$
Let us now substitute this into the first equation:
$$x_{n+1}=x_n + y_n = x_n + x_{n-1}$$ 
Let us again shift the equation by $1$ to get:
$$x_{n}= x_{n-1} + x_{n-2}$$ 
This the recursive formula for the Fibonacci sequence where:
$$ x_n = \frac{\phi^n-(-\phi)^{-n}}{\sqrt{5}} $$
The limit now becomes:
$$ \lim _{n\to\infty} \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} = \lim _{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{\phi^{n+1}-(-\phi)^{-n-1}}{\sqrt{5}}}{\frac{\phi^n-(-\phi)^{-n}}{\sqrt{5}}} = \phi = \frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2} $$

Comment: Thank you. Dinno Koluh.

Comment: I am glad for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Let $ \lim _{n\to\infty}  x(n+1)/x(n) = a$

$\lim_{n\to\infty}  \   { x(n+1)/x(n)= \lim_{n\to\infty}  \ x(n)/x(n-1) = a} $

Given $y(n)=x(n-1)$

$x(n+1)=x(n)+x(n-1)$  (Eq. 1)

$x(n+1)/x(n)=1+x(n-1)/x(n)$

$a=1+1/a$

$a^2-a-1=0$  (Eq. 2)

$a=\frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2}$ is a solution to (Eq. 2)

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).